# All possible combinations of numbers of length 5 in a 4X4 matrix

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

i have a matrix

```
1 9 2 3
5 0 0 6
8 4 4 8
2 3 7 8
```

I need to find all possible combinations of numbers of length 5.

constraints:

1. Starting form a any position in the matrix you can only move to your next immediate neighbor i.e if u start form say (0,0) your neighbor must be (0,1),(1,1),(1,0) and if you pick a position then form that position you can only move to its immediate neighbor and so on.
2. The length of the number must be 5 digit's i.e for example if i start from (0,0) with value 1 i can produce a sequence 15151 or 19232 or 10063 so on you can move in any sequence with the constraint 1 applied.
3. The solution must produce the output in 7sec and python is preferred since its my favorite. ;)

OK i missed some things the program must use all 16 numbers i.e it must use all the 16 numbers as initial and produce the 5 digit sequence.

Comment: And your specific question is? SO likes to see effort before we put in effort. Thanks.

Comment: oops the matrix came up in one line. Dranit  its a 4x4 matrix:(

Comment: Constraint 3. sounds badly formed to me. Basically you could get around it using better hardware with PyPy or Cython.

Comment: If this is homework you should tag it as such

Comment: I wrote the code but its pretty bad and it takes around 30sec to to stop printing all combinations. I'm also trying to write it in C hoping it wold be faster.

Comment: Why don't you show us your code so we could tell you if your algorithm could be improved.

Comment: This seems like homework or an interview question. Should be tagged as such.

Comment: yes its a home work that i got form my professor and the actual grid size is now 5X5 and 9 digits for my c code. since it took 30 sec in the first trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to think about how to start at one position in the matrix and move to an adjacent one.

The brute force method is simply to list all available cells and all adjacent cells for each:

```
nextpos = {
    (0,0): [(1,0), (1,1), (0,1)],
    (0,1): [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (0,2)],
    (0,2): [(0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (0,3)],
    (0,3): [(0,2), (1,2), (1,3)],
    # etc
}
allpos = nextpos.keys()
```

For a problem this small, this is pretty simple; however, there is always a chance of typos. Another solution is to write a generator function:

```
def nextpos(p,w=4,h=4):
    """
    @param p     Current position tuple (x,y)
    @param w     Width of matrix
    @param h     Height of matrix

    Generate all matrix cells adjacent to the current one
    """
    rel = ((-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1))

    x,y = p
    for dx,dy in rel:
        nx,ny = x+dx, y+dy
        if 0<=nx<w and 0<=ny<h:
            yield (nx,ny)
```

Once we know which cells are next to each other, we can proceed to seek valid paths:

```
def matrix_path(pathLen, startFrom=None):
    """
    @param pathLen    Length of path to return
    @param startFrom  Initial location

    Generate all adjacency paths through the matrix
    """

    # bad path length - quit gracefully
    if pathLen<1:
        yield []
        return

    # no starting point specified - start at any point
    if startFrom is None:
        for pos in allpos:
            for res in matrix_path(pathLen, pos):
                yield res
        return

    # end of path
    if pathLen==1:
        yield [startFrom]
        return

    # from current point, recurse to find rest of path
    for pos in nextpos[startFrom]:
        for morePath in matrix_path(pathLen-1, pos):
            yield [startFrom]+morePath
```

We can find out how long this takes by profiling:

```
import cProfile

def test():
    sols = [i for i in matrix_path(5)]
    print len(sols), "paths found"

cProfile.run("test()")
```

which returns

> 16860 paths found
>            121497 function calls (16865 primitive calls) in 0.678 CPU seconds

This returns a list of lists of cell-positions; we want to turn this into the actual values from the matrix,

```
def path_vals(mx, path):
    """
    @param mx    Matrix data
    @param path  List of cell positions

    Return list of values from list of cell positions
    """

    return tuple([mx[x][y] for x,y in path])
```

Then

```
mx = [
    [1,9,2,3],
    [5,0,0,6],
    [8,4,4,8],
    [2,3,7,8]
]

def test():
    sols = [path_vals(mx, i) for i in matrix_path(5)]
```

We also want to reduce the list to unique results:

```
def test():
    usol = list(set([path_vals(mx, i) for i in matrix_path(5)]))
    print len(usol),"unique results"

cProfile.run("test()")
```

which gives us

> 8651 unique results
>            138357 function calls (33725 primitive calls) in 0.845 CPU seconds

Comment: @hugh- neat! i was looking for a way to log the results in python. is there a way to read the matrix command line input file and use it for this program?

Comment: the file is basically a text file with .txt

Comment: @CodeJunki: ya want me to do everything for you??  allpos is a list of (x,y) offsets, essentially all possible starting positions in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Scala (for the 5x5 version with 9 digits, starting from the middle) (with an [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/92He5)). It took 5 seconds to execute on my (fairly slow) computer.

```
object Main {

    val matrix = List(List("1", "9", "2", "3", "1"),
                      List("5", "0", "0", "6", "1"),
                      List("8", "4", "4", "8", "1"),
                      List("8", "4", "4", "8", "1"),
                      List("2", "3", "7", "8", "1"))

    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = nums(2, 2, 9) map println

    def nums(r: Int, c: Int, left: Int) : List[String] =
        if (!(matrix isDefinedAt r) || !(matrix(r) isDefinedAt c)) List()
        else if (left == 0) List("")
        else for ((dr, dc) <- List((0,1), (1,0), (-1,0), (0,-1));
                  tail <- nums(r + dr, c + dc, left - 1))
                yield matrix(r)(c) + tail
}
```

Here is a solution in Java (with an [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/j2UwF)).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    static String[][] matrix = {{"1", "9", "2", "3"},
                                {"5", "0", "0", "6"},
                                {"8", "4", "4", "8"},
                                {"2", "3", "7", "8"}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String i : nums(0, 0, 5))
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static List<String> nums(int r, int c, int left) {

        if (r < 0 || r >= matrix.length || c < 0 || c >= matrix[r].length)
            return Collections.emptyList();

        if (left == 1)
            return java.util.Arrays.asList(matrix[r][c]);

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int[] delta : new int[][] {{0,1}, {1,0}, {-1,0}, {0,-1}})
            for (String tail : nums(r + delta[0], c + delta[1], left-1))
                result.add(matrix[r][c] + tail);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Execution took 8 ms on my computer.

---

If you want to speed it up, you should definitely cache the results. There are several ways of getting two steps down, and two steps to the right using 4 digits. All of which will share same possible tails (namely `nums(row + 2, col + 2, x)`).

Comment: i believe it dose not work for all the 16 positions as initial with the same speed. 8msX16 cool :)

Comment: Thats true, you get more results by starting in the middle. (150 instead of 58 to be precise). Takes 18 ms on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this rather easily with recursion and backtracking.

Have a recursive function along the lines of:

foo(x,y,depth)

and then recursively try moving each direction that is inbounds and valid. When the max depth (5) is reached, you have a number. Then it is just bookkeeping to build and combine lists.

**Edit**

A little more info..

```
foo( x, y, depth, seq )
```

where seq is a string of the sequence up to this point. It returns a list of strings which are the solutions.

Base case: the depth is 5, in which case just return a list with the current number concatenated onto seq.

Otherwise check the bound for each direction, and if it is valid, call foo with the proper coordinates, depth +1, and the current number concatenated onto seq. Combine all the resulting lists together and return that.

Invoke this function for each initial spot with a depth of one, a sequence of "", and then combine all 16 of these results together.

Note that because this is recursive it works fine for this problem size, but can get slow very quickly. Although because it is depth-limited I would not expect it to be as much of an issue.

**1503** unique solutions

**Edit 2**

my search function is pretty similar to what you had, but look at what bounds are being checked and what values are returned etc..

```
def foo(x,y,depth,seq):
    if depth == 5: return [seq + str(matrix[x][y])]

    cur = []
    seq = seq + str(matrix[x][y])
    if (y - 1) >= 0: cur.extend(search(x,y-1,depth+1,seq))
    if (x + 1) < len(matrix[0]): cur.extend(search(x+1,y,depth+1,seq))
    if (y + 1) < len(matrix): cur.extend(search(x,y+1,depth+1,seq))
    if (x - 1) >= 0: cur.extend(search(x-1,y,depth+1,seq))

    return cur
```

The way I check the four directions could be cleaned up and made more 'pythonic', but this was more just a proof of concept that you could solve the problem sufficiently fast.

Comment: @Falmarri - indeed, but if it is limited to 5 digit numbers I would expect it to be reasonable. Also it does not sound like this is some sort of production code that is speed critical - as long as it fits the 7 second guideline.

Comment: yup recursion seemed slow to me in python :( so trying in C.

Comment: @CodeJunki: is the actual problem size bigger than the example you gave? I coded up the example matrix in Python, with recursion as I described, and it takes practically no time to run at all.

Comment: @ghills- well did it work for all the 16 nodes as initial?? whats the time it took??

Comment: @CodeJunki: Yes it ran for each of the 16 nodes as the starting node, and it took 0.06 seconds.

Comment: @CodeJunki: see my updated answer for some more details. It is very short and should not take you long to implement

Comment: sorry if i'm asking for too much but can i have a look at the code i cant seem make out how to code it :( i used django to code a web app but did'nt go thru the whole basics of coding in python

Comment: try coding it based on the edited directions. If you can't get it to work, post what you tried and how it is not working in your question and I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: your solution dose not move to positions (i+1),(j+1) or (i-1),(j-1) if you start at the center it has more positions to move to than just those

Comment: that solution is limited to 4X4 matrix is it doesn't seem to work for 5X5 with depth 9

Comment: Ah I didn't realize diaganol moves were allowed, it is easy enough to add though. That solution works fine for 5x5 to depth 9 if you change the depth comparison.

Comment: i made the modification and run it for 5X5 and depth=8 and it took a long time to finish with duplicate results. is there a way avoid calculating duplicate results

Comment: if you have a list l, you can eliminate duplicates by converting it to a set and back. `l = list(set(l))`

Comment: yeah but thats after calculating duplicates. I bet if you could somehow avoid calculating duplicates the time would reduce a lot!..

Answer (score 0):

Look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) combinatoric generators for inspiration:

- product()
- permutations()
- combinations()
- combinations_with_replacement()

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
    def foo(x,y,depth,seq):

```
def search(x,y,depth,seq):

if depth == 8: 

    return [seq + str(matrix[x][y])]

cur = []

seq = seq + str(matrix[x][y])

if (y - 1) >= 0: 

    cur.extend(search(x,y-1,depth+1,seq))

if (x + 1) < len(matrix[0]): 

    cur.extend(search(x+1,y,depth+1,seq))

if (y + 1) < len(matrix): 

    cur.extend(search(x,y+1,depth+1,seq))

if (x - 1) >= 0: 

    cur.extend(search(x-1,y,depth+1,seq))

if (x + 1) < len(matrix[0]) and (y + 1) < len(matrix): 

    cur.extend(search(x+1,y+1,depth+1,seq))

if (x - 1) >= 0 and (y - 1) >=0: 

    cur.extend(search(x-1,y-1,depth+1,seq))

if (x + 1) < len(matrix[0]) and (y - 1) >= 0: 

    cur.extend(search(x+1,y-1,depth+1,seq))

if (x - 1) >= 0 and (y + 1) < len(matrix): 

    cur.extend(search(x-1,y+1,depth+1,seq))

return cur
```

matrix = [[1,1,2,3,5],

```
    [2,3,4,5,5],

    [5,5,2,3,3],

    [9,9,5,4,2],

    [9,9,5,4,2],

    ]
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
print search(0,0,0,"")
```

I ran this code it took 19~20 sec to stop. that too just for one initial location, also it produced a lot of duplicate results. I ran this on 2.2Ghz core 2 duo processor my old pc got hung and python.exe crashed :p.

Comment: is there a way to avoid calculating duplicate results??